# Passing arguments to StringTemplate function

Tags: java, stringtemplate, jdbi

Let's say I have

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT :someField FROM myTable")
String fetchField(@Bind("someField") final String columnName);
```

I want to move this into a stg file using `UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator` and then from there, use group files and templates. I need to pass this argument to another function, i.e.

```
@SqlQuery
String fetchField(@Bind("someField") final String columnName);

// in the stg file
fetchField() ::= <<
<someOtherMethod(:someField)> <! I need to pass someField to this other function ->
>>

someOtherMethod(columnName) ::= <<
 ... All the query is generated here
>>
```

This is not working. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `@Define` annotation to provide attributes to [StringTemplate4](http://jdbi.org/#_stringtemplate_4), and then, you would use it as `<someField>`. But, in this way, query written will be open for SQL injection